# Implementation of Newaer SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

I want to know the basic implement `newaer SDK` (https://www.newaer.com) in my app for iOS Devices. I could not find anything useful on SO or any where else on internet regarding the **Implementation of Newaer SDK**. I did a lots of R&D but could not find any solution. if anyone has worked with `newaer SDK` earlier that would be great. Please help. I have some basic questions on this and if you know any tutorial that would be great. My questions are:-

1. How to find out the unique `NewaerID` of my device.
2. With the help of `Newaer SDK` can we find the android SDK.

There are some other questions. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the SDK for iOS can not see Android devices, however, the opposite is not true. i.e. Android can see iOS devices which are broadcasting.

NewAer is currently working on a new API which will provide this feature.

The current iOS SDK does not reveal the NewaerID of a an iOS device. The next release for iOS will include api calls to retrieve this identifier.

In terms of implementation, the best guide is to look at the sample application in the SDK bundle. If you can explain your use case a little more I may be able to help you to reach it using the existing SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick. My exact situation is **I want to store the NewAerIDs of all the users on the server and when the my device search the another device then i will send the NewAerID to the server and server will return me the information regarding that NewAerID**. Is there any way i can do this from the existing SDK Or What do you Suggest for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to wait for the next release to support this use case as we are not revealing the ID in the current SDK.

Comment: Hey Ankit, I am pleased to let you know that the NewAer 3.0 SDK just dropped which allows Android and iOS to see each other. You want to enable the new NewAer Device scanner on both platforms. See http://newaer.com for the download bundles.

Comment: hey, @NickPalmer, where could we get the tutorial for the newaer implementation in android?

Comment: There is a sample application included with every SDK download. That is the best tutorial we have right now.

Answer (score 0):

just drag the newaer-sdk-proximity-ios.framework to your project,and register a app and app id in https://www.newaer.com/landing